# Return Object type as Interface C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, interface

I am trying to return Interface as my return type from a method which provides data from two different data source with couple of different column. My implementation goes as below:

Interface:

```
public interface IBasicDTO
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string EstablishmentCode { get; set; }
    DateTime? DetailsUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    DateTime? PaymentUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    UpdateStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

BasicDTO abstract class:

```
public abstract class BasicDTO : IBasicDTO, IModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DetailsUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PaymentUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public UpdateStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

Derived Class CBasicDTO:

```
public class CBasicDTO : BasicDTO
{
    public CBasicDTO() : base() { }
    public int? CID { get; set; }
    public string UniqueIdentificationNo { get; set; }
}
```

Derived Class LBasicDTO

```
public class LBasicDTO : BasicDTO
{
    public LBasicDTO() : base() { }
    public int? LID { get; set; }
    public string LIdentificatonNo { get; set; }
}
```

Implantation 1 Method:

```
public IList<IBasicDTO> GetBasicData(int CID_LID, bool IsByLID)
    {
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@p_CID", Value = CID_LID };
        if (IsByLID)
        {
            LLDbContext dataContext = new DBContextProvider().GetContext<LLDbContext>();
            var data = dataContext.Database.ExecuteProcedure<LBasicDTO>("Read_BasicDetails", parameter);
            return (IList<IBasicDTO>) data;

        }
        else
        {
            CIDbContext dataContext = new DBContextProvider().GetContext<CIDbContext>();
            var data = dataContext.Database.ExecuteProcedure<CBasicDTO>("Read_BasicDetails", parameter);
            return (IList<IBasicDTO>)data;
        }
    }
```

I am not getting any error at Compile time, but at run-time I am getting bellow error at `return (IList<IBasicDTO>)data;`

Error:

> `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[NonTableTypes.CBasicDTO]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList1[NonTableTypes.IBasicDTO]'.`

If I go with below implementation:

```
public IList<IBasicDTO> GetBasicData(int CID_LID, bool IsByLID)
    {
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@p_CID", Value = CID_LID };
        if (IsByLID)
        {
            LLDbContext dataContext = new DBContextProvider().GetContext<LLDbContext>();
            var data = dataContext.Database.ExecuteProcedure<IBasicDTO>("Read_BasicDetails", parameter);
            return (IList<IBasicDTO>) data;

        }
        else
        {
            CIDbContext dataContext = new DBContextProvider().GetContext<CIDbContext>();
            var data = dataContext.Database.ExecuteProcedure<IBasicDTO>("Read_BasicDetails", parameter);
            return (IList<IBasicDTO>)data;
        }
    }
```

I am getting below error at run-time:

> `The result type 'NonTableTypes.IEPFBasicDTO' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor.`

Merging this data points in single data source is not an option for us as these data source is very large and CBasicDTO is already in production.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: A `List<LBasicDTO>` is *not* a `List<IBasicDTO>`. If that cast was allowed, you'd be able to insert a `CBasicDTO` into it, despite that *single* list object still claiming to be a list of `LBasicDTO` objects.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I understood the point, but how can I return two different derived class list from a method based on condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast each of the elements in the collection to the instance type, linq has a [`.Cast<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-5.0) extension that will help:

```
public IList<IBasicDTO> GetBasicData(int CID_LID, bool IsByLID)
{
    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@p_CID", Value = CID_LID };
    if (IsByLID)
    {
        LLDbContext dataContext = new DBContextProvider().GetContext<LLDbContext>();
        var data = dataContext.Database.ExecuteProcedure<LBasicDTO>("Read_BasicDetails", parameter);
        return data.ToList().Cast<IBasicDTO>().ToList();

    }
    else
    {
        CIDbContext dataContext = new DBContextProvider().GetContext<CIDbContext>();
        var data = dataContext.Database.ExecuteProcedure<CBasicDTO>("Read_BasicDetails", parameter);
        return data.ToList().Cast<IBasicDTO>().ToList();
    }
}
```

- You cannot simply cast the result, because in many implementations the result will be `IEnumerable<T>` but not an `IList<T>`
- It *IS* necessary to call `data.ToList()` to execute the DB query first.
- It is *NOT* necessary to cast to `IList<T>` as a `List<T>` already matches that signature
- We have to call `.ToList()` at the end to match the `IList<T>` return signature.

Comment: It worked as expected. Description is very helpful to understand the concept.

Comment: The final `ToList()` should be sufficient to ensure that the query is executed and materialized. In most cases, the intermediate `ToList()` would be unnecessary, so I'm not sure why you say it's necessary.

Comment: In .Net FX you have to materialize first, the `Cast` has to be done in memory, otherwise EF throws the same error OP listed at runtime. I think in EF.Core this has been fixed, it silently materialises first when it recognises that it can't be done in the DB.